# add active class to current hyperlink using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I'm trying to show which link is current active using j query in aspx web form.
first I generated all hyperlinks from my db to gallery.aspx by this function from behind code:

```
public string build_Gallery_Category()
{
    string post = "";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    clsBusiness cls = new clsBusiness();
    dt = cls.Fill_In_DataTable("GalleryGroup");
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            post += "<li><a href='gallery.aspx?gid=" + dt.Rows[i]["GalleryId"].ToString() + "'><strong>" + dt.Rows[i]["GalleryName"] + "</strong></a></li>";
        }
    }
    return post;
}
```

So, after i call that method, all of hyper links appear on gallery.aspx, as bellow :

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
       <%=viewCategory %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

after that, add this style to gallery.aspx:

```
<style>
    .active { background: #f00; }
</style>
```

after all, I added jquery code on end of from :

```
<script>
    $("menu li").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("menu li a.active").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class  
        $("a", this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab  
    });
</script>
```

but my code does't work... so please help me. thanks alot...

Comment: `build_Gallery_Category` is on `gallery.aspx`?

Comment: no it's on seprate class and call it from gallery.aspx.cs

Answer (score 1):

looks like your jQuery selector is wrong

```
$("menu li")
```

must be

```
$("#menu li")
```

and

```
$("menu li a.active")
```

must be

```
$("#menu li a.active")
```

without the **`#`** you cannot access the div-tag with id menu

Comment: thanks you're right but now, the hyperlink href is disabled and does't send query to server.

Comment: I think this is because of the e.preventDefault(); If you click a link  also the li tag is clicked and further action is prevented.